# Associating multiple notes(data model) to a student(data model)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my web application, I'm building a note taking feature. I want to have notes appear for certain students, I want teachers to be able to write notes about students. So I want to be able to associate notes with students. How can I go about doing something like this?

The obvious solution would be to make a Notes(belongs_to student) and student (has_many notes). I think this is the way but i'm not sure. The only problem is I'm in charge of Note. Other people are in charge of students, sessions, etc.

Problem: I'm in charge of Notes while others are in charge of students, sessions, etc.

What can i do, what should I be researching. Any help would be appreciated.
Schema.rb

```
  create_table "session_notes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "note"
    t.integer  "session_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "sessions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "start_time"
    t.datetime "end_time"
    t.integer  "session_teacher"
    t.integer  "session_student"
    t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
  end

  create_table "students", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "full_name"
    t.string   "screen_name"
    t.string   "icon"
    t.string   "color"
    t.string   "contact_info"
    t.text     "description"
    t.integer  "session_interval"
    t.integer  "school_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",       null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",       null: false
  end

  create_table "teachers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "user_name"
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.datetime "last_login"
    t.string   "full_name"
    t.string   "screen_name"
    t.string   "icon"
    t.string   "color"
    t.string   "email"
    t.text     "description"
    t.string   "powers"
    t.integer  "school_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
  end
```

Sessions_note_controller

```
class SessionNotesController < ApplicationController
  #before_action :set_session_note,  only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /session_notes
  # GET /session_notes.json
  def index
    @session_note = SessionNote.new
    @session_notes = SessionNote.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  # GET /session_notes/1
  # GET /session_notes/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /session_notes/new
  def new
    @session_note = SessionNote.new
  end

  # GET /session_notes/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /session_notes
  # POST /session_notes.json
  def create
    @session_note = SessionNote.new(session_note_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @session_note.save
        format.html { redirect_to session_notes_url, notice: 'Session note was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :index, status: :created, location: @session_note }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @session_note.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /session_notes/1
  # PATCH/PUT /session_notes/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @session_note.update(session_note_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @session_note, notice: 'Session note was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @session_note }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @session_note.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /session_notes/1
  # DELETE /session_notes/1.json
  def destroy
    @session_note.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to session_notes_url, notice: 'Session note was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    # def set_session_note
    #   @session_note = SessionNote.find(params[:id])
    # end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def session_note_params
      params.require(:session_note).permit(:note, :session_id, :created_at)
    end
end
```

Sessions_controller

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_session, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /sessions
  # GET /sessions.json
  def index
    @sessions = Session.all
  end

  # GET /sessions/1
  # GET /sessions/1.json
  def show
    @student = Student.find(@session.session_student)
    @teacher = Teacher.find(@session.session_teacher)
  end

  # GET /sessions/new
  def new
    @session = Session.new
  end

  # GET /sessions/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /sessions
  # POST /sessions.json
  def create
    @session = Session.new(session_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @session.save
        format.html { redirect_to @session, notice: 'Session was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @session }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @session.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /sessions/1
  # PATCH/PUT /sessions/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @session.update(session_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @session, notice: 'Session was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @session }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @session.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /sessions/1
  # DELETE /sessions/1.json
  def destroy
    @session.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to sessions_url, notice: 'Session was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_session
      @session = Session.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def session_params
      params.require(:session).permit(:start_time, :end_time, :session_teacher, :session_student)
    end
end
```

Comment: I dont quite understand why a session belongs to both a teacher and a student. As far as i understand your application only teachers can login so the session should belongs only to a teacher and a note should belong to a student instead of a session . This way a teacher could add notes to any student or multiple students

Comment: @RadaBogdan I thought the same thing. I went to my superior/instructor and apparently session_notes belongs to session not students. Which is why i'm trying to figure out how to associate session notes to a student.

Comment: Session is not authentication in this exercise, it's the relationship between teacher and student. SessionNote belongs to Teacher and Student by belonging to Session, because it belongs to Teacher and Student. Look at my answer for more ;)

Comment: Aha . Now i understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you need is
one-many relation between your `students` and `session_notes` table

- one `Student` instance has_many session_notes
- one `SessionNote` instance belongs_to student

one-many relation between your `teachers` and `session_notes` table

- one `Teacher` instance has_many session_notes
- one `SessionNote` instance belongs_to teacher

generate migration to add `student_id` on `session_notes` table

```
rails g migration add_student_id_to_session_notes student_id:integer
```

generate migration to add `teacher_id` on `session_notes` table

```
rails g migration add_teacher_id_to_session_notes teacher_id:integer
```

then run the migrations `bundle exec rake db:migrate`

```
# app/models/session_note.rb
class SessionNote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student
  belongs_to :teacher
end

# app/models/student.rb
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :session_notes
end

# app/models/teacher.rb
class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :session_notes
end
```

Use them:

```
Student.last.session_notes
Teacher.last.session_notes
```

Comment: No need for a many to many between teacher and student when one is available. Essentially a session_note already belongs to a student and teacher by belonging to sessions. And he seems to want to track which session a note originated from.

Comment: @fbelanger Yes we have a teacher can conduct study sessions with one student. During that session a teacher can write a note about that student during that session and i want that note to be associated to that student automatically.

Comment: @Kapaz you're adding a lot of content that belongs in your question, not this comment section.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble picking out a question in your post.  Can you try to get a little more specific on what your goal is or what you don't understand?
That being said...

If I'm understanding correctly, you're wanting to set up a `has_many` type relationship but you aren't sure how to do it, yet.  If that's the case, take a look at this piece of the [rails docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#associating-models) for associating one model with another.

Basically, with the code I see above, you would set up a new model and put it in the `<your app's root directory>/app/models/` directory.  That class would have a few lines that might resemble this

```
class SessionNote < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :Teacher

  # code that does things you need your model to do
end
```

and so on.
I'm not even sure if I'm on the right track with the answer so I'll post this and let you update with a bit more detail.
Let me know if you have any questions about what I meant or if I'm not giving you the info you want.

Comment: Pretend I'm a  teacher. While I have this web app open if i want to write a quick note about a student I can write it and I can choose who the note is about in case later I want to view notes about a certain student.                                                     **We have a feature where the teacher can conduct study sessions with students. While the timer/session for that student is running I want to be able to write a note and have that note be associated with that student automatically without the teachers input.

Answer (score 0):

From the nature of your question, I will assume that you're pretty new to software.

You are in charge of Notes, however the note **feature** can effect and depend on other **features**.

Not sure why you're showing sessions_controller, but I'm glad you did. I realize now that a `Session` is a many to many between students and teachers. Got completely caught up with the meaning of sessions in software.

So looking at your schema file, your associating the session to the note.

The session represents an instance of a teacher and student. So far so good.

Because a session belongs to a teacher and student, we can leverage that to express the same for notes, while saying that a note belongs to a specific session.

I guess what you really want to know is how to code it. Because you've only added boilerplate controller code and haven't provided any model code at all, classic :)

```
class SessionNote < ActiveRecord::Base # ApplicationRecord for Rails 5+
  belongs_to :session
  delegate :teacher, :student, to: :session
end

class Session < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :teacher, foreign_key: 'teacher_session'
  belongs_to :student, foreign_key: 'student_session'
  has_many :session_notes
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sessions
  has_many :session_notes, through: :sessions
end

class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sessions
  has_many :session_notes, through: :sessions
end
```